# svg mouseover doesn't work in zurb foundation nav topbar

Tags: svg, zurb-foundation

I'm working with zurb foudation and have a roll over on an svg that is within the header. If the svg is under 

then the roll over effect on the svg doesn't work. but if I remove either the section tag or the data-topbar attribute then it works fine. you can see an example of all three variations here:
http://firefields.com/foundation-5.5.0/icon-issue.html

and this is the svg code

```
<svg version="1.1" id="headTest" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 42 42" enable-background="new 0 0 42 42" xml:space="preserve" >

<defs>
<mask id="Mask">
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M25.4,12.7L15.3,28.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.5c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.2,0.5L27,13.9c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.7-0.8-0.8
        C25.9,12.9,25.7,12.8,25.4,12.7z"/>
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M14.3,25.9c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.4l1.5-2.3c-1,0.1-2.1,0.4-3.3,0.9c-2.1,1.1-4.2,3-5.8,5.4
        c-0.5,0.7-0.8,1.4-1.1,2.1c0.5,0.7,0.9,1.2,1.5,1.8c0.4-0.9,0.8-1.9,1.4-2.8C10.6,28.5,12.4,26.8,14.3,25.9z"/>
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M20.3,37.6c1.6-2.5,2.5-5.3,2.5-7.8c0-1.7-0.4-3.2-1-4.3l-1.2,2.1c0.2,0.7,0.4,1.4,0.3,2.2
        c0,2.1-0.8,4.6-2.2,6.7c-0.5,0.7-1,1.4-1.5,2c-2.8-0.7-5.3-1.9-7.6-3.6C9.2,35.6,9.1,36.3,9,37c2.6,2,5.6,3.2,8.8,3.7
        c0.6-0.6,1.1-1.1,1.6-1.8l0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0C19.7,38.5,20,38.1,20.3,37.6z"/>
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M38.7,12c-0.8-1.7-2-3.3-3.3-4.6c-0.1,0.7-0.4,1.5-0.7,2.2c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1l-0.1-0.1c-0.4,1-0.8,2-1.5,3
        c-1.4,2.1-3.2,3.8-5,4.8c-0.7,0.3-1.3,0.6-1.9,0.7l-1.2,2.1c1.3,0.1,2.7-0.3,4.1-0.9c2.1-1.1,4.2-3.1,5.8-5.5
        c0.5-0.7,0.8-1.4,1.1-2.1c0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.7,1.3c4.5,8.9,0.9,19.7-7.9,24.2c-2.4,1.2-4.9,1.9-7.5,1.9c-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.4-1.5,2
        c3.3,0.2,6.7-0.6,9.9-2.1C39.9,33.9,43.8,21.8,38.7,12z"/>
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M12.9,5c2.9-1.5,6-2.1,9.1-1.9c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.3,1.7-1.9c-3.8-0.5-7.8,0.1-11.6,2c-9.9,4.9-13.9,17-8.9,26.8
        c1,2.1,2.4,3.9,4.1,5.5c0.1-0.7,0.4-1.5,0.7-2.1c-1.1-1.2-2.1-2.6-3-4.2C0.5,20.3,4,9.5,12.9,5z"/>
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M22.4,5.6c-1.6,2.5-2.5,5.3-2.5,7.8c0,1.4,0.2,2.6,0.7,3.5l1.4-2.2c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.3
        c0-2.1,0.8-4.6,2.2-6.7c0.7-1.1,1.4-2.1,2.1-2.8c2.6,0.8,5,2.1,7.1,4.1c0.3-0.8,0.5-1.6,0.5-2.2c-2.3-2-5-3.3-7.9-4
        c-0.7,0.5-1.2,1-1.8,1.7c0.3,0.1,0.2,0-0.1,0C23.4,4,22.9,4.8,22.4,5.6z"/>
</mask>
</defs>

<g mask="url(#Mask)">
<circle fill="#222222" class="icon-background-circle" cx="21" cy="21" r="21"/>
<circle fill="#73e8eb" class="icon-foreground-circle" cx="21" cy="21" r="0">
    <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="r" begin="hoverZone.mouseover" to="21" dur="0.15s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="r" begin="hoverZone.mouseout" to="0" dur="0.15s" fill="freeze" />
</circle>
</g>

<rect id="hoverZone" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="42" fill-opacity="0"  />

</svg>
```

hope you can help.

Comment: also this seems to work in firefox. seems to be a chrome issue

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the `<section>` element.

When an an SVG is embedded via the `<img>` element, animations are allowed, but interaction (such as mouse events) are not.  This is for privacy reasons.

Use `<object>` or `<embed>` instead.

Comment: I've changed the answer to privacy rather than security. Nobody's going to take over your browser but they might figure out what you're up to.

Comment: The security of your privacy ;)

Comment: Thank you Robert.
I'm actually only using the img tag to make it easy for front end developers to build pages. it inserts the svg code when the page renders. I've updated the link and the explanation to show the problem with the section tag. Sorry about the confusion.